# How do I uninstall subversion?

Tags: debian, uninstall, svn

At some point I built/installed subversion 1.14.2 under Debian.
I want to undo all that and its dependents.
I re-downloaded the tarball, extracted, and configured.
There is **no** `uninstall` target of any kind within the `Makefile`

Anyone know how I'm supposed to uninstall it?

Comment: How you installed is how you uninstall it.

Comment: So, just to make sure, you did `./configure`, `make` and `make install`, correct?

Comment: That's correct: the usual three. The makefile has no "uninstall" target of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when you build applications from source they install under /usr/local/...

Assuming your install didn't overwrite anything that was already in that directory tree (i.e. you are simply looking to delete the files that were installed).

- Find the main binary `which svn`
- Check when you installed it `ls -l /usr/local/bin/svn`
- Search for all files under /usr/local that were install at approximately the same time: `find /usr/local -newermt "2021-12-08" \! -newermt "2021-12-10"`
- Remove them `rm ...`

Note: Most of the time it is only the binaries that cause issues, so a short cut is just to look through /usr/local/bin and remove anything that looks relevant.

Also in your case, if you have only ever installed one thing from source it's quite likely you could just delete all files under /usr/local (just leave the directories in place).

Answer (score -1):

So I finally found a solution. It was not ... "intuitive."
Apparently, it's not necessarily uncommon for manual builds to *not* include an `uninstall` target.

I followed these instructions: [... how can I uninstall or remove completely?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1278739/1585688)

TL;DR

```
$ ./configure [WHATEVER_OPTIONS_YOU_USED]
$ make
$ sudo checkinstall ; # pick a unique but relevant name
$ sudo dpkg --install --force-overwrite YOUR_PACKAGE.deb
$ sudo apt remove YOUR_PACKAGE
```

Worked flawlessly. Bye-bye manually-built `svn`